# How to generate desired number of pulp.LpVariable in Python (such as x11, x12, x21, x22 and so on) and store them in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, pulp

I want to define a certain number of mathematical x variables. I'm using the term "mathematical x variables", because these are mathematical variables that I want to represent with Python variables. I need these x values to later use in an LP (Linear Programmıing) problem.

In Python PuLP library, we can generate a number of x variables in such a way:

```
x = {i: LpVariable(name=f"x{i}", lowBound=0) for i in range(1, 5)}
```

Then when we use `print(x)` we get the dictionary:

{1: x1, 2: x2, 3: x3, 4: x4}

Where each x value such as x1, x2 etc. is type `pulp.pulp.LpVariable` .

But I want a code to generate mutliple branches of x. Which I can use to generate as much of branches I want to.

I want to store all x values (such as x11, x12, x21, x22...) in a dictionary.

Here is the solution I wrote:

```
# Defining the decision variables
# Here, we create a nested dictionary to store the x variables
# Using a dictionary also allows us to store the indice values
x = {i: 
         {j: 
              {k: 
                   {l: 
                       LpVariable(name=f"x{i}{j}{k}{l}", lowBound=0, cat="Integer") 
                    for l in range(1, 3) } 
               for k in range(1, 4) } 
          for j in range(1, 4) } 
     for i in range(1, 3) }
```

This solution prints out as:

```
{1: {1: {1: {1: x1111, 2: x1112},
         2: {1: x1121, 2: x1122},
         3: {1: x1131, 2: x1132}},
     2: {1: {1: x1211, 2: x1212},
         2: {1: x1221, 2: x1222},
         3: {1: x1231, 2: x1232}},
     3: {1: {1: x1311, 2: x1312},
         2: {1: x1321, 2: x1322},
         3: {1: x1331, 2: x1332}}},
 2: {1: {1: {1: x2111, 2: x2112},
         2: {1: x2121, 2: x2122},
         3: {1: x2131, 2: x2132}},
     2: {1: {1: x2211, 2: x2212},
         2: {1: x2221, 2: x2222},
         3: {1: x2231, 2: x2232}},
     3: {1: {1: x2311, 2: x2312},
         2: {1: x2321, 2: x2322},
         3: {1: x2331, 2: x2332}}}}
```

Which is what I want. Now the problem is, I want to do the same job automatically. So let's say with a function something like this;

`def generate_nested_variables(dimension_number, dimension_ranges)`

Which generates desired number of dimensions (nests) with desired ranges. So let's say

`def generate_nested_variables(2, [3,5])`

would print out this:

```
{1: {1: x11, 2: x12, 3: x13, 4: x14, 5: x15},
 2: {1: x21, 2: x22, 3: x23, 4: x24, 5: x25},
 3: {1: x31, 2: x32, 3: x33, 4: x34, 5: x35}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like you are trying to make multi-dimensional constraints *the hard way*.

You should make your indexing sets for the multiple constraints separately, and then use the `.dicts()` feature in `pulp` to construct variables--much easier and you don't have to monkey around with the string labelling stuff.  And, then it is much easier to index your variables by items in the multi-dimensional indices later on.  I'm not sure how you would do that in your example.

Here are a couple of ideas.  If you search my profile for something like `LpVariable.dicts` I'm sure you will find others.

#### Code:

```
import pulp as pl
from itertools import product

# some indexing sets (or dimensions)

d1 = [4, 5, 6]

d2_size = 4

d2 = list(range(1, d2_size + 1))

d3 = ['red', 'green', 'blue']

d123 = list(product(d1, d2, d3))

# declare the LP

prob = pl.LpProblem('example')

# make some variables

x = pl.LpVariable.dicts('x', indices=d1)

y = pl.LpVariable.dicts('y', indices=[(i, j) for i in d1 for j in d2])

z = pl.LpVariable.dicts('z', indices = d123)

# some example constraints

prob += x[4] >= 3.4

# sum over d2 dimension for each i in d1
for i in d1:
    prob += sum(y[i, j] for j in d2) >= 1.2

# sum over all the greens in z
greens = [(i, j, k) for i, j, k in d123 if k=='green']
prob += sum(z[green] for green in greens) <= 4

print(prob)
```

#### Output:

```
example:
MINIMIZE
None
SUBJECT TO
_C1: x_4 >= 3.4

_C2: y_(4,_1) + y_(4,_2) + y_(4,_3) + y_(4,_4) >= 1.2

_C3: y_(5,_1) + y_(5,_2) + y_(5,_3) + y_(5,_4) >= 1.2

_C4: y_(6,_1) + y_(6,_2) + y_(6,_3) + y_(6,_4) >= 1.2

_C5: z_(4,_1,_'green') + z_(4,_2,_'green') + z_(4,_3,_'green')
 + z_(4,_4,_'green') + z_(5,_1,_'green') + z_(5,_2,_'green')
 + z_(5,_3,_'green') + z_(5,_4,_'green') + z_(6,_1,_'green')
 + z_(6,_2,_'green') + z_(6,_3,_'green') + z_(6,_4,_'green') <= 4

VARIABLES
x_4 free Continuous
y_(4,_1) free Continuous
y_(4,_2) free Continuous
y_(4,_3) free Continuous
y_(4,_4) free Continuous
y_(5,_1) free Continuous
y_(5,_2) free Continuous
y_(5,_3) free Continuous
y_(5,_4) free Continuous
y_(6,_1) free Continuous
y_(6,_2) free Continuous
y_(6,_3) free Continuous
y_(6,_4) free Continuous
z_(4,_1,_'green') free Continuous
z_(4,_2,_'green') free Continuous
z_(4,_3,_'green') free Continuous
z_(4,_4,_'green') free Continuous
z_(5,_1,_'green') free Continuous
z_(5,_2,_'green') free Continuous
z_(5,_3,_'green') free Continuous
z_(5,_4,_'green') free Continuous
z_(6,_1,_'green') free Continuous
z_(6,_2,_'green') free Continuous
z_(6,_3,_'green') free Continuous
z_(6,_4,_'green') free Continuous
```